# How do I write a conditional (IF DATA EXISTS) LINQ statement without repetition?

Tags: sql-server, linq

I need to write a Linq query where the condition like this:

- when data exists then the join will be  `INNER JOIN`
- when data is not exists then the join will be  `LEFT JOIN`.

```
bool ifexists =  db.Users.Any(u => u.id== 1);
IQueryable<modelname> query;
if(ifexists == true)
{
    query=my inner join linq;
    query = from s in query select s;
    return query.ToList();
}
else 
{
    query=my left join linq;
    query = from s in query select s;
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Now how I can write this Linq? Is there any way to write this linq in a single `Linq` statement - I don't want to write the linq twice?

Answer (score 3):

You can conditionally compose on an `IQueryable` before evaluating it against the database - this will allow you to at least partially DRY up the common actions on the different legs of your branching:

```
var query = db.SomeTable
    .AsQueryable() // Not needed if `db.SomeTable` is already a Queryable
    .Where(x => ** common predicates on x ** ));
    // NB : Do not materialize here!

if(exists) // Don't need == true
{
     query = query
      .Where(x => ** branch 1 predicates **));
}
else
{
     query = query
      .Where(x => ** branch 2 predicates **);
}
return query
  .Select(q => ** common fields to project **)
  .OrderBy(q => ** common ordering **)
  .ToList(); // Materialize right at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

You Want like That?

```
bool ifexists =  db.Users.Any(u => u.id== 1);

var query=ifexists==true ? (my inner join linq) : (my left join linq);

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thnaks @Abu Huzaifa

Answer (score 0):

```
   First create object of of database Context named **Objcontext** 
    now hold the variable in var the query would be like following 




 var Result = from a in Objcontext.tbl1  where !Objcontext.tbl2.Any(m=>(m.sid==a.aid)&&(m.mid==80))
    select a; 



 If data is exists in the databse it will cheack using !Objcontext 
    I hope it will helpfull
```